# Why is American and French notation different for open intervals (x, y) vs. ]x, y[?

Tags: mathematics, notation

The Americans and the French use a different notation for [open intervals](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OpenInterval.html): The Americans use (x, y) while the French use ]x, y[. How did this notational divergence appear?

Comment: The square brackets notation is due to Bourbaki.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Thanks, I had no idea it was so recent. Do you know why they chose this notation?

Comment: Some discussion on this topic [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430851/notation-for-intervals) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181750/what-does-the-notation-0-1-mean/181751#181751). One commenter suggest that the backward brackets might have been introduced by Bourbaki to prevent confusion with ordered pairs. I am still at a loss for a documented history, but it is at least a part of an old ISO standard. I am not seeing it in the latest standard [ISO 80000-2](http://www.ise.ncsu.edu/jwilson/files/mathsigns.pdf).

Comment: I guess it is intuitive (inclusion/exclusion of the endpoints depends on the direction of the bracket), but I have not found anything written by them stating this or some other motivation explicitly.

Comment: @J.W.Perry Thanks! I had indeed [went through the standard](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/704855/24265) for that reason, see notation 2-6.10 last column.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Good eye, hence still in the standard. Not sure how I missed it, I must not have been looking hard enough. I would still like to see the documented history, or at least see the primary document text trace of the ]a, b[ notation. Where's a Florian Cajori when you need him?!

Comment: I've heard in a math class some years ago, that the motivation behind the $]\cdot,\cdot[$ notation is that the $(\cdot,\cdot)$ notation is reserved for [ordered pairs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair).

Comment: The `] [` notation is used in Belgium too, also in the Dutch-speaking part.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Notation $()$ is traditional, and $].[$ was introduced by [Bourbaki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Bourbaki).

Much of the Bourbaki notations and terminology became standard, but English speaking people are the most conservative ones in this respect:-) 
(Recall the history of the metric system:-)

Another example of the same is "injection", "surjection", "bijection".
Many English authors still write "one-to-one", "onto" and "one-to-one and onto".

Another example: Bourbaki taught us that "positive" is $\geq 0$,
and "strictly positive" is $>0$.

But many people still prefer "positive" to mean $>0$ and "non-negative" for $\geq0$.

Remark. I am educated in Ukraine in 1970-s, and I experienced a strong influence
of Bourbaki on education. But I still like $(,)$, perhaps just for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: Thanks, very interesting, I had no idea that the definition "positive" is $\geq 0$ was from Bourbaki as well, I am always having trouble with that in the US.

Comment: When you say Bourbaki taught the meaning of positive as $\geq 0$, do you really mean that pre-Bourbaki in France the word positif in math meant $> 0$ rather than $\geq 0$? In my experience, положительный means $> 0$, but did you ever have teachers in the USSR suggest it should mean $\geq 0$?

Comment: @KCd: I suppose "positif" meant in pre-Bourbaki France the same as "positive" in English. Concerning Soviet teachers of 1960-70th, some of them were Bourbakists, others not. Yes, I had teachers who promoted Bourbaki terminology, but I understand that this was not very common. I studied in Western Ukraine, not in Moscow.

Comment: A friend of mine asked a member of Bourbaki, let's call him X-X. X, about this and indeed the usage is due to Bourbaki. X-X. X said Bourbaki wanted to allow the notation $\subset$ to include the possibility of equality, and not just mean a strict subset. Compatibly with that, they wanted $<$ to mean less than or equal to and $>$ to mean greater than or equal to. This is why Bourbaki started using the word positif to mean greater than or equal to 0.

Comment: Yes, and Bourbaki had partial success: everyone uses $\subset$ nowadays in their sense.

Comment: "Positive" positively means greater than 0. A positive zero has its place in economy and commerce and unexact speaking. Bourbaki's opinion is completely irrelevant in this and other respects..

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: From my, admittedly rather limited, experience I'd say the opposite is (still) true: since $<$ is usually interpreted as a strict inequality, I do prefer writing $\subseteq$ for (not necessarily strict) inclusion.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko:  You experienced a strong influence of Bourbaki on education? This is in contrast with  a statement of Murray Gell-Mann: "Nature Conformable to Herself", Bulletin of the Santa Fe Institute, 7 (1992) 7-10: "Pure mathematics and science are finally being reunited and, mercifully, the Bourbaki plague is dying out. (In the late Soviet Union they never succumbed to it in the first place)"

Comment: "Yes, and Bourbaki had partial success: everyone uses ⊂ nowadays in their sense." Who is everyone? If you see him, tell him that he is wrong.

Comment: @Otto: I use it in that way, and I am not wrong.

Comment: @Otto: And I. In fact, I don't think I EVER used $\subseteq$ in my long career, and had to look to my LaTeX manual, when typing this comment. Same applies to most authors of books and papers that I read.